# Why does this shgo minimization fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize, operations-research

I am trying to use linear constraints with [shgo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html). Here is a simple MWE:

```
from scipy.optimize import shgo,  rosen


# Set up the constraints list
constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, i=i: x[i+1] - x[i] - 0.1} for i in range(2)]

# Define the variable bounds
bounds = [(0, 20)]*3

# Call the shgo function with constraints
result = shgo(rosen, bounds, constraints=constraints)

# Print the optimal solution
print("Optimal solution:", result.x)
print("Optimal value:", result.fun)
```

An example solution satisfying these constraints is:

```
rosen((0.1, 0.21, 0.32))
13.046181
```

But if you run the code you get:

```
Optimal solution: None
Optimal value: None
```

It doesn't find a feasible solution at all!  Is this a bug?

## Update

@Reinderien showed that the problem is the default sampling method 'simplicial'. Either of the other two options make the optimization work. Concretely,  replace the `result =` line with

```
result = shgo(rosen, bounds, sampling_method='halton',constraints=constraints)
```

and you get

```
Optimal solution: [1.08960341 1.18960341 1.41515624]
Optimal value: 0.04453888080946618
```

If you use `simplicial` you get

```
Failed to find a feasible minimizer point. Lowest sampling point = None
```

although I don't know why.

(Deleted incorrect part of question)

Comment: Broadly: I've counted one clear bug (halton failing to respect `args`). The inverted constraint is working as expected, and for everything else (nondeterministic runtime, simplicial failure to find global minimum) this is about as fragile as you can typically expect from a non-commercial optimizer. You basically need to perform a manual hyperparameter search over all of the methods and tunables for the optimizer to figure out how to get it to work reasonably; it isn't magic.

Comment: @Reinderien thank you. What was the halton failure? I am not sure we discussed that.

Comment: If you remove the `partial` approach I demonstrated and pass the index in `args` instead, it (sometimes) fails to pass those args to the constraint method.

Comment: I do like your partial approach. It's very elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html):

> Only the COBYLA and SLSQP local minimize methods currently support constraint arguments. If the constraints sequence used in the local optimization problem is not defined in `minimizer_kwargs` and a constrained method is used then the global constraints will be used. (Defining a constraints sequence in `minimizer_kwargs` means that constraints will not be added so if equality constraints and so forth need to be added then the inequality functions in constraints need to be added to `minimizer_kwargs` too).

`shgo` does not support direct linear constraints, only callables. You should usually prefer matrix-based constraints when they're linear, which in this case requires using `minimizer_kwargs` instead.

But! You also should not use the default sampling method *simplicial* which performs poorly on your problem and produces a non-optimal minimum. Either *halton* or *sobol* do better, regardless of whether they're provided matrix constraints or callables. Efficiency varies depending on whether you also provide the Jacobian. All methods together:

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import shgo, rosen, LinearConstraint


def spacing(x: np.ndarray, index: int) -> float:
    return x[index + 1] - x[index] - 0.1


def spacing_jacobian(x: np.ndarray, index: int) -> np.ndarray:
    j = np.zeros(3)
    j[index + 1] = 1
    j[index] = -1
    return j


lin_constraint = {
    'minimizer_kwargs': {
        'constraints': LinearConstraint(
            A=np.array((
                (-1,  1,  0),
                ( 0, -1,  1),
            )),
            lb=(0.1, 0.1),
        ),
    },
}
call_constraint = {
    'constraints': [
        {
            'type': 'ineq',
            'fun': partial(spacing, index=i),
        }
        for i in range(2)
    ],
}
j_constraint = {
    'constraints': [
        {
            'type': 'ineq',
            'fun': partial(spacing, index=i),
            'jac': partial(spacing_jacobian, index=i),
        }
        for i in range(2)
    ],
}

for i_constraint, constraint in enumerate((lin_constraint, call_constraint, j_constraint)):
    for method in ('sobol', 'halton', 'simplicial'):
        result = shgo(
            func=rosen,
            bounds=[(0, 20)]*3,
            sampling_method=method,
            **constraint,
        )
        if result.success:
            print(f'{i_constraint} {method:10} '
                  f'{result.nit:4} {result.nfev:4} {result.fun:8.6f}')
```

```
0 sobol         2  334 0.044539
0 halton        2  417 0.044539
0 simplicial    2   24 6.420000
1 sobol         2  490 0.044539
1 halton        2  218 0.044539
2 sobol         2  490 0.044539
2 halton        2  206 0.044539
```

But repeated runs produce iteration counts all over the place; these methods are non-deterministic. Given that the inter-method performance is a wash, I recommend the matrix-based approach and either *sobol* or *halton*. You ask:

> If I simply add sampling_method='halton' to my code in the question I get the same answer you do. Does that mean that I did set the constraints correctly?

Correct-ish, but if there's no difference in performance between your callable constraints and matrix constraints, matrix constraints should be preferred as they're inherently simpler to an optimizer and imply the Jacobian with no extra work.

> a trivial change to the constraint will make shgo fail for all three sampling methods

No, it doesn't fail; it does exactly what you tell it to.

> This constrains the parameters of solutions to be in decreasing order instead of increasing order.

No, it doesn't. Re-examine your math, and invert the coefficient signs for your decision variables.

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import shgo, rosen, LinearConstraint


def spacing(x: np.ndarray, index: int) -> float:
    return x[index] - x[index+1] - 0.1


def spacing_jacobian(x: np.ndarray, index: int) -> np.ndarray:
    j = np.zeros(3)
    j[index + 1] = -1
    j[index] = 1
    return j


lin_constraint = {
    'minimizer_kwargs': {
        'constraints': LinearConstraint(
            A=np.array((
                ( 1, -1,  0),
                ( 0,  1, -1),
            )),
            lb=(0.1, 0.1),
        ),
    },
}
call_constraint = {
    'constraints': [
        {
            'type': 'ineq',
            'fun': partial(spacing, index=i),
        }
        for i in range(2)
    ],
}
j_constraint = {
    'constraints': [
        {
            'type': 'ineq',
            'fun': partial(spacing, index=i),
            'jac': partial(spacing_jacobian, index=i),
        }
        for i in range(2)
    ],
}

for i_constraint, constraint in enumerate((lin_constraint, call_constraint, j_constraint)):
    for method in ('sobol', 'halton', 'simplicial'):
        result = shgo(
            func=rosen,
            bounds=[(0, 20)]*3,
            sampling_method=method,
            **constraint,
        )
        if result.success:
            print(f'{i_constraint} {method:10} '
                  f'{result.nit:4} {result.nfev:4} {result.fun:20.18f} {result.x}')
```

```
0 sobol         2  324 0.056257754369320817 [0.89242801 0.79242801 0.62797312]
0 halton        2  192 0.056257656181717651 [0.89243175 0.79243175 0.62794038]
0 simplicial    2  100 0.056257645173465855 [0.89245899 0.79245899 0.62799362]
1 sobol         2  237 0.056257635321605277 [0.89244688 0.79244688 0.62797206]
1 halton        2  198 0.056257635321603119 [0.89244688 0.79244688 0.62797206]
2 sobol         2  237 0.056257635321605104 [0.89244688 0.79244688 0.62797206]
2 halton        2  200 0.056257635321394606 [0.89244691 0.79244691 0.62797208]
```

Comment: There are some parts I don't understand. If I simply add  sampling_method='halton' to my code in the question I get the same answer you do. Does that mean that I did set the constraints correctly? Also, if I change -0.1 to +0.1 in your solution I get an answer that doesn't fit the new constraints.

Comment: @Simd re sampling: I edited the answer. re. constraints: if changing the constraint sign is a requirement, you need to edit your question to explain that and explain why. The constraints work in both cases but your intention is not clear, and I have some guesses why.

Comment: I have updated the question. If you feel I should accept your answer and ask another one with the slightly changed constraint just let me know.  I am trying to use shgo for optimizing various problems and I am worried it seems to be really prone to failure.

Comment: Why does specifying the constraints as  a matrix imply the Jacobian? You still need to compute all the first-order partial derivatives don't you?

Comment: No: the first-order partials for the constraint matrix are trivial and the optimizer can do that on its own